# Python String to triplet color

Tags: python, string, colors, pygame, rgb

Hov can I make a string triplet to a RGB color? Like this:

```
color = "255,255,255"
background.fill((color))
```

This code gives me "invalid color argument".
Why I want to do it this way? This string is saved in a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pygame.Surface.fill` expects:

> The color argument can be either a RGB sequence, a RGBA sequence or a
>   mapped color index. If using RGBA, the Alpha (A part of RGBA) is
>   ignored unless the surface uses per pixel alpha (Surface has the
>   SRCALPHA flag).

You could try something like

```
def str2rgb(s):
    rgba = s.split(",")
    if len(rgba) not in (3, 4):
        return (0, 0, 0)
    return tuple(map(int, rgba))


>>> color = "255,255,255"
>>> str2rgb(color)
(255, 255, 255)
>>> color2 = "255,255,255,0"
>>> str2rgb(color2)
(255, 255, 255, 0)
```

Comment: Nice! This function looks way better than the one i wrote. Thanks a bunch!